# How to include deployment files with a TFS build

Tags: .net, deployment, tfs

After my TFS build completes, I need to run a couple of .bat files to rename/copy files so that the package is ready for a particular environmeent.

I've included these in one of my class library projects so they set to them "copy if newer", but idealy, I would like to include these in a Solution Items folder. However when I add them to the solution items folder, I can't set them to "copy if newer" so they don't end up in my build output folder.

Where do other people store these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a folder to your Visual Studio projects called "Deployment" and set the `Copy to Output Directory` attribute accordingly.

You'll also then know which deployment artifacts belong to each component.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping them in a solution folder is a reasonable approach. You can edit the *.*proj file for your library project to copy the files you need by using the [MSBuild Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx).